# Issues with Ubuntu 16.04LTS on Dell Gaming PC

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, nvidia

I have a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 5000 i7 touchscreen gaming laptop with a 4GB NVIDIA graphics card.

I downloaded the ISO image from Ubuntu directly and transferred it to a USB drive using Rufus.

I attempted to install it (being able to dual boot Windows 10) and the Ubuntu screen froze up on me.

I researched the problem and discovered I had to disable secure boot. I disabled it and changed my bootup mode to legacy. I was still experiencing problems and I researched it again. I modified some script and erased 'quiet splash'.

Keep in mind I am not an expert programmer by any means.

Anyways, I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I am having issues when I place my PC in "suspend" mode and try to resume. It freezes or glitches, then I have to completely restart my machine. I am also experiencing issues with the text being WAY too small, almost to unreadability. Maybe I am missing a driver?

Comment: By the way, I am still fairly new to Ubuntu and programming. I am a paramedic who decided to self-teach myself programming. If possible, please explain like I am 5.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or, 
First restart your computer and check for an irregular bootup to Ubuntu. Next, login and Power management and change suspend settings to "Never Suspend." Lastly Use Ubuntu Tweak to increase font.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: I have tried 'apt-get update' several times. I am trying 'dist-upgrade' now. Maybe I need a driver for graphics card?

Comment: To activate drivers, you can go to driver manager and select your proprietary driver. Also, apt-get update is just to tell the computer that there are packages for upgrading. apt-get upgrade is for "upgrading."

Comment: Neither helped. I am still experiencing issues.

Comment: I  rather stick to my usual Ubuntu. Just need someone who knows how to fix this issue.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Try this ppa    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak